# Html <object>, read javascript detection from the outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

index.html
`<object id="battle" data="battle.html"></object>`

has a animation I want to show, but when the animation is finnish I want it to close.
I have tried making the webpage disappear and it did work but the screen after it was unclickable

battle.html
`document.getElementById("battlebody").style.display="none";`
[!The image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkEV7.png) This code is played when the animation is done. Basically I made a border around it to tell where it is while invisible.

Well I was wondering if it is possible to edit the `<object>` markup in index.html not in battle.html like I have done.

an example
index.html

```
<body>
<object id="battle" data="battle.html"></object>
</body>
```

the battle.html

```
<body>
    <button id="" onclick="closing(); ">close</button>
    <script>
    function closing() {
    window.close()
    </script>
</body>
```

I kinda want to make the object close but it doesn't work that way so making the object `display:none;` but for that too work you will need to add that js code to the index.html, but the index.html does not read into the `<object>`

Comment: make a fiddle pls..

Comment: @Bla... can't since fiddle only uses 1 html page.

Comment: `object id="battle"` ... `document.getElementById("battlebody").style.display="none";` ... two different ID's ... why? have you tried `document.getElementById("battle").style.display="none";`

Comment: @JaromandaX Its 2 different html files,
I have already tried giving the same id

Comment: huh? so, the object has one id, and something not shown has the other id, you wnat to hide the object by using the id of whatever you haven't shown ... how is anyone supposed to help if you don't post the relevant code ... is the code that "hides" the content in the page inside the object or in the page that contains the object?

Comment: @JaromandaX I editing the question up to make more sense.

Comment: use an iframe instead of object, then the pages will be able to interact a whole lot cleaner - to be honest, I've never seen an object used to show a html page! is there a reason you're using an object?

Comment: @JaromandaX smh

Comment: @Bamuel WTAF!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the [`window.parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/parent)[`.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) method.

**Targeted page**

```html
<html>
<body>
  <script>
    setTimeout(function() {
      parent.postMessage('close-me', '*');
    }, 2000);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```js
window.onmessage = function(e){
  if(e.data === 'close-me'){
    console.log("should remove");
    obj.parentNode.removeChild(obj);
    }
  };
```

```css
object{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<object id="obj" data="data:text/html; charset=utf8, %3Chtml%3E%3Cbody%3E%3Cscript%3EsetTimeout(function()%7Bparent.postMessage('close-me'%2C'*')%3B%7D%2C2000)%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E%3C%2Fbody%3E%3C%2Fhtml%3E"></object>
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out soon